# Authorization Error while loading Java cacerts programatically

Tags: java, security, filenotfoundexception, x509

I am trying to import a X509 certificate programatically in my client GUI, using the method such as described in this answer [Import Certificate Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755180/java-ssl-connect-add-server-cert-to-keystore-programatically). My code looks like:

```
char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

char SEP = File.separatorChar;
File dir = new File (System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP + "lib" + SEP + "security");
File keystoreFile = new File(dir, "cacerts");

KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(targetStream);

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);

trustStore.load(in, password);
in.close(); 


trustStore.setCertificateEntry("alias", c);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
trustStore.store(out, password);
out.close();
```

But when I run the program and try to import it I get an exception like:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security\cacerts (Access is denied)
```

I know the password "changeit" is the default password and it is the right one because I cross checked it using the commandline keytool.

Is there something I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

**Solution:**

Thanks to the link in Manuel's reply I found the solution for this. Obviously the Java folder in Program Files did not have the right permissions for the OS user (to write). I want to know if this is by default, even in the case of Linux OS? Is there a work around it without changing the permissions manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've the same problem as described [Access is denied java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561386/access-is-denied-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

You need to define a file name, not only a directory as seen in your code:

```
File dir = new File (System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP + "lib" + SEP + "security");
File keystoreFile = new File(dir, "cacerts"); <-- file name missing, 'cacerts' is a directory
```