# Cannot save file with .txt extension (anything other extension works)

Tags: java, save, bufferedwriter

#

SOLVED 20170607 -It turns out this was an IDE installation error.  I system restored to when I was using an older Eclipse and Java 6.  I then installed the latest Eclipse and Java 8 and the file saved with no errors.

#

What's going on here?  Google as well as many sites such as this do not seem to enlighten me.

I using Eclipse 4, Windows 7 SP 1 and Java 8 (121 64 bit)

I have looked at [Access is denied java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561386/access-is-denied-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

It says the issue is due to file permissions.  I can read txt files with no trouble and I can write to new or existing files as long as they do not have .txt as their extension.  This is explained in the v1 of my question.  Even so, I gave admin and the currently logged on user (me), full permissions to the director and the exception's still thrown. I can load files with no problems (see the question section titled #####LOADING FILES#####)

I'm trying to work out how to save files.  The code I have created works with the extensions .exe, .mp3, .foo, .doc, .exe.

When I use .txt. and IOExcepton, access denied is thrown.  link to image: http://design.paulyeatman.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/IOException-savefile-20170602.png

Here's the program code.  I've included everything (so methods not yet written etc, the one I'm interesting in is "private void saveFile(String fileName, String sample)"

```
/* This program is to teach myself to save a file using as an example, a program that maintains a list of DVD's along with release date and whether or not has been watched (so a DVD name and and 2 associated variables I'll probably track with an ArrayList).
 * Where a DVD has been watched, user should be able to modify existing entry to this effect.
 * The list of DVD's, release date and watch state are all saved into a persistent file for future editing.
 * 
 * 
 * might be insightful http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-file-utilities-open-read-write-copy-files as has some pre coded classes
 */

import acm.program.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;  // not used
import java.nio.charset.Charset; // not used

public class saveData extends ConsoleProgram implements saveDataConstants    {

    public void run() {
        // guts of program here
        chooseFile();
        addToDataList();
//      saveFile(fileName, text);s
}


/* this asks the user if the have a file or if they want to create a new file */

    private void chooseFile() {
        println ("Choose your file type");
        println("1. You want to create a new file.");
        println("2. You want to open an existing file.");
        int fileChoice = readInt ("");
        println("You chose: " + fileChoice);
        if (fileChoice == 1) {
            createNewFile();
        }
        if (fileChoice == 2) {
            existingFile();
        }

    }

/* an existing file is read into a bufferedReader */

    private void existingFile() {
        println("existingFile method launched");
    }

/* a new file is created by assigning it a file name which is held in memory until the save option is launched */

    private void createNewFile() {
    fileName = readLine ("Enter in you filename: ");
    fileName = fileName + FILE_EXTENSION;

}

/* this add to the file in active memory */

private void addToDataList() {
    println("This is the addToDataList method");
    println("We want arrays to handle Movie Title, Release Date, Watched (or not)");
//      println("A sentinel of Q is planned to be used to enter the saveFile method");

    //the next line throws an IOException.  Why, file path?  something else???  Nah, the .txt extension. .doc, .mp3. foo. exe. .png all used and work with no IOEx

    saveFile(fileName, sample);
//      saveFile();
}

/* this has test string for the file */

private String testString(String text) {
    String sample = "This should text should wind up in the text file the program should create";
    return (sample);
}

/* this saves the new data to the file (hopefully, just appends, will it overwrite?  who cares?) 
 * 
 * The fileName is remembered as it should be.  Here we assume it will save to some default location.
 * 
 * The test string is correctly gathered from the testString(String text) method.
 * */


private void saveFile(String fileName, String sample) // adapted from http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-file-save-write-text-binary-data
//  throws IOException
    {
    String textToSave = testString(sample);

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

    println("This is the saveFile method.  Presumably it saves the file.");
    println("");
    println("the filename is remembered as: " + fileName);
    println("");
    println("the text to save is: " + textToSave);
    println("");
    File fileNameSaved = new File (fileName);

    try{
        BufferedWriter file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (fileNameSaved));  // true will add to the file and not overwrite

//      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (file, true));  // true will add to the file and not overwrite
        // #############################
        // Note, the BufferedWriter line saves the file name as "file". and the txt is put into it.
        // When I remove the quotes, an IOException results despite file = the correct name.  Since tracked error down to extension on .txt

        // see if this helps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

        file.write(textToSave);
        file.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm
        System.err.println();
    }
    println("The file has saved if the program gets this far."); // even if IOEx thrown, this displays.
}

/* Private variables follow */
String fileName;
String textToSave;
String sample;
}
```

File 2 just has the constants and they are feed into the methods correctly.

LOADING FILES

I created a file called existing.txt.  That is read into the program by a buffered reader with no problem at all.  Calling

```
println("Should be x1 Element, so the ref 0 element is: " + workingData.get(0));
```

Gives the output as "Should be x1 Element, so the ref 0 element is: This has been loaded from an existing text file called "existing.txt" "

What I'm really asking

Should my code work and Windows has an issue with Eclipse saving text files (seems to not be the case as not the same as [Access is denied java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561386/access-is-denied-java-io-filenotfoundexception) ), is there something else I need to learn about this function of Java or is my code lacking something?

/\ Based on my testing, Windows must have had an issue with Eclipse trying to save files, so yes in the end permission errors.

Comment: The file must already exist, and have file permissions set such that you can't update it from that process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access is denied java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561386/access-is-denied-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is this something specific to txt files?
Eg. if I type in "existing" a file called existing.foo is created.

If I make a file and give it the foo extension, then the code above over writes the file with the new existing.foo and includes the sample text.

Comment: Also Possible duplicate of [java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281143/java-io-filenotfoundexception-access-is-denied)

Comment: I've tested the above code on a snapshot of my existing VM running Eclipse 3.2.1 and Java 6 Update 2 and the 8.txt file is created and saved successfully.

So, in conclusion, the code works with Eclipse 3.2.1 and Java 6 Update 2

The code does not work with: Eclipse 4.6.3, Windows 7 SP 1 and Java 8 (121 64 bit).