# Use of Scala Loan pattern in Success Case

Tags: scala, file, try-catch, ioexception

I'm following the tutorial from [Alvin Alexander](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples) to use `Loan Pattern`

Here is the code what I use -

```
val year = 2016
val nationalData = {
val source = io.Source.fromFile(s"resources/Babynames/names/yob$year.txt")
    // names is iterator of String, split() gives the array
    //.toArray & toSeq is a slow process compare to .toSet  // .toSeq gives Stream Closed error
    val names = source.getLines().filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(",")(0)).toSet
    source.close()      
    names
    // println(names.mkString(","))     
}   
println("Names " + nationalData)

val info = for (stateFile <- new java.io.File("resources/Babynames/namesbystate").list(); if stateFile.endsWith(".TXT")) yield {
    val source = io.Source.fromFile("resources/Babynames/namesbystate/" + stateFile)
    val names = source.getLines().filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(",")).
        filter(a => a(2).toInt == year).map(a => a(3)).toArray // .toSet        
    source.close()      
    (stateFile.take(2), names)      
}
    println(info(0)._2.size + " names from state "+ info(0)._1)
    println(info(1)._2.size + " names from state "+ info(1)._1)
    for ((state, sname) <- info) {
     println("State: " +state + " Coverage of name in "+ year+" "+ sname.count(n => nationalData.contains(n)).toDouble / nationalData.size) // Set doesn't have length method
}
```

This is how I applied `readTextFile`, `readTextFileWithTry` on the above code to learn/experiment `Loan Pattern` in the above code

```
def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
    try {
        f(resource)
    } finally {
        resource.close()
    }

def readTextFile(filename: String): Option[List[String]] = {
    try {
        val lines = using(fromFile(filename)) { source =>
            (for (line <- source.getLines) yield line).toList
        }
        Some(lines)
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => None
    }
}

def readTextFileWithTry(filename: String): Try[List[String]] = {
    Try {
        val lines = using(fromFile(filename)) { source =>
            (for (line <- source.getLines) yield line).toList
        }
        lines
    }
}

val year = 2016
val data = readTextFile(s"resources/Babynames/names/yob$year.txt") match {
    case Some(lines) =>
        val n = lines.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(",")(0)).toSet
        println(n)
    case None => println("couldn't read file")
}

val data1 = readTextFileWithTry("resources/Babynames/namesbystate")
data1 match {
    case Success(lines) => {
        val info = for (stateFile <- data1; if stateFile.endsWith(".TXT")) yield {
            val source = fromFile("resources/Babynames/namesbystate/" + stateFile)
            val names = source.getLines().filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(",")).
                filter(a => a(2).toInt == year).map(a => a(3)).toArray // .toSet
            (stateFile.take(2), names)
            println(names)
        }
    }
```

But in the second case, `readTextFileWithTry`, I am getting the following error -

```
Failed, message is: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\Babynames\namesbystate (Access is denied)
```

I guess the reason for the failure is from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561386/access-is-denied-java-io-filenotfoundexception) what I understand - 
`I am trying to open the same file on each iteration of the for loop`

Apart from that, I have few concerns regarding how I use -

- Is it the good way to use? Can some help me how can I use the TRY on multiple occasions?
- I tried to change the return type of `readTextFileWithTry` like `Option[A]` or `Set`/`Map` or Scala Collection to apply higher-order functions later on that. but not able to succeed. Not sure that is a good practice or not.
- How can I use higher-order functions in `Success` case, as there are multiple operations and in `Success` case the code blocks get bigger? I can't use any field outside of `Success` case.

Can someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem has nothing to do with "*I am trying to open the same file on each iteration of the for loop*" and it is actually the same as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561508/182660)

Unfortunately you didn't provide stack trace so it is not clear on which line this happens.  I would guess that the falling call is

```
val data1 = readTextFileWithTry("resources/Babynames/namesbystate")
```

And looking at your first code sample:

```
val info = for (stateFile <- new java.io.File("resources/Babynames/namesbystate").list(); if stateFile.endsWith(".TXT")) yield {
```

it looks like the path `"resources/Babynames/namesbystate"` points to a directory. But in your second example you are trying to read it as a file and this is the reason for the error. It comes from the fact that your `readTextFileWithTry` is not a valid substitute for [`java.io.File.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()) call. And `File.list` doesn't need a wrapper because it doesn't use any intermediate closeable/disposable entity.

P.S. it might make more sense to use [`File.list(FilenameFilter filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list(java.io.FilenameFilter)) instead of `if stateFile.endsWith(".TXT"))`